# Location Module fields are not available under Search api fields

Tags: entities, search, location

I am using Search API's Default Node index. I am using Location module to store Location data. But location module fields are not available under Search API Related fields.

I know this has been an issue but was just wondering if this could ever get fixed? I could have used Geolocation or Geofield modules and used the fields in search api. But unfortunately when i used location module i was not using Search API.

Now I have 10000 Nodes using location module to store location details.

What could be the solution? How to make these fields to be used under Search api so that i can use facets and eventually show them on MAP.?

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No Answers or solutions? Is there a way we can push in data from Location module's Latitude and Longitude to Geolocation field's Latitude and Longitude and then use those fields in Search API for Indexing?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1480906#comment-9588531), you can achieve that by means of a combination of modules:

Search API Location + Search API Solr + Location field (creating an aggregated location field).

You will need an extra step by implementing `hook_search_api_solr_documents_alter()` because the longitude and latitude need to be indexed with the right format.